# filter out undefined properties in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array consisting of objects. Here's an example :

```
[
{events: Array(5), conditions: {…}},
{events: Array(5), conditions: {…}}
{conditions: {…}, awaits: Array(0), events: Array(1), pid: "123"}
]
```

The objects differ as you can see. Some have the property 'pid' and some don't. And thats what this question is all about.

I want to assign the ones with pid to a new array with objects that contain pid.

Lets say this array is stored in match.entries. Well here's what i've tried.

// `aa = match.entries.filter(entry => {return typeof entry.pid !== 'undefined'})`

This doesnt seem to work.

My entire code :

```
    let aa = [];

   conditionalMatches.forEach(match => {
      aa = match.entries.filter(entry => {return typeof entry.pid !== 'undefined'})
    });
```

Returns empty array.

Comment: You are overwriting the `aa` variable every time. So you'd have an empty array if the last item in `conditionalMatches` has no entries that have an undefined `pid`.

Comment: @VLAZ i thought so at the beginning, so i used concat but still no success

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `array.filter((arrayItem) => arrayItem.pid)` that will also work for `null` values. And since `pid` is a string type, it will consider the value as `0` but will skip for empty value as `""`.

```js
const conditionalMatches = [
  [{
      events: Array(5),
      conditions: {}
    },
    {
      events: Array(5),
      conditions: {}
    },
    {
      conditions: {},
      awaits: Array(0),
      events: Array(1),
      pid: ""
    },
    {
      conditions: {},
      awaits: Array(0),
      events: Array(1),
      pid: "123"
    }
  ],
  [{
      events: Array(5),
      conditions: {}
    },
    {
      conditions: {},
      awaits: Array(0),
      events: Array(1),
      pid: "123"
    }
  ],
  []
];


let aa = [];

conditionalMatches.forEach(match => {
  let filterArr = match.filter((arrayItem) => arrayItem.pid);
  if(filterArr.length !== 0) {
   aa.push(filterArr);
  }
});

console.log(aa);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I am a bit further now, it only pushes the values that i want. However it still pushes empty arrays when the value doesnt match the filter condition

Comment: Filter returns an empty array if it doesn't find any matches. If you didn't want that to happen you could use another for loop and an if statement, an only push when the if statement is true.

Comment: @Kevin.a updated my answer. You can check the length of array before pushing it.

Comment: I think even if you check the length, you're still just pushing an array, so you'll end up with a nested array. If you just wanted the objects pushed you could do `aa.push(...filterArr)`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find the objects where pid is defined

```js
const array = [
  {events: Array(5), conditions: {}},
  {events: Array(5), conditions: {}},
  {conditions: {}, awaits: Array(0), events: Array(1), pid: "123"}
];

const filteredArray = array.filter((arrayItem) => arrayItem.pid !== undefined);
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Based on comments below, and this really does have to happen in a for loop, you could do something more like this?

```
conditionalMatches.forEach(match => {
  match.entries.forEach(entry => {
    if(entry.pid){
       aa.push(entry);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: In my case this is all happening inside a forEach loop and in your answer you're not assigning the returned values to a empty array.

Comment: well @Kevin.a your code and data is simply incomplete, I think this answered based on the data set you gave, not on your potential code given

Comment: WHY does it have to be a forEach? filter is better than a forEach